# Protecting Angular 5 app against undefined array interpolation in template

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add multilingual capabilities to an Angular 5 app, but I'm not sure I've chosen the right approach for it.

I have defined this 2 types in a service:

```
type appMsgTuple = {
  [key : string] : string | string[]
}

type appMsgs = {
  es : appMsgTuple,
  en : appMsgTuple
}
```

So, I define variables to hold the translations for the different components of the app like:

```
export var MSG_USER : appMsgs = {
  "es" : {
    "MSG_USER_1" : "Por favor, introduzca sus datos de acceso",
    "MSG_USER_BUTTONS" : [ "ACCEDER", "Síganos" ]
  },
  "en" : {
    "MSG_USER_1" : "Please, type your login details",
    "MSG_USER_BUTTONS": [ "LOGIN", "Follow us"]
  }
}
```

In each component, I import the appropriate strings from the service:

```
// USER COMPONENT
[ ... ]
import { MSG_USER } from 'app/services/languages.service';

public MSGS : any = {};   // We'll use this to 'point' to the right language in MSG_USER (see below)
```

And, to make it more concise, I assign the variable `MSGS` to the right language (chosen by the user) like this:

```
// USER COMPONENT
[ ... ]

ngOnInit() {
  this.MSGS = MSG_USER[selUsr.selectedLanguage];
  [ ... ]
}
```

Finally, in the template I use the `MSGS` variable to display the different strings, in this way:

```
<h5 class="fwcBlue">{{ MSGS['MSG_USER_1'] }}</h5>

<button label="{{ MSGS['MSG_USER_BUTTONS'][1] }}" [disabled]="!formModel.valid || formModel.pristine" (click)="onLogin()">    
</button>
```

This works, BUT there's a big problem with it: if I mistype any of the keys (for example, I type `MSGS['MSG_USER_BUTTTTTTTONS'][1]`, the application crashes because it doesn't exist and Javascript can't access position 1 of undefined.

How could I avoid this potential risk? Thanks in advance,

Comment: See [here](https://angular.io/guide/i18n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular templates support [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) (Elvis operator) for this purpose.

It [isn't supported for bracket notation](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17181), so a safeguard is necessary in this case:

```
<button
  *ngIf="MSGS['MSG_USER_BUTTONS']"
  label="{{ MSGS['MSG_USER_BUTTONS'][1] }}"
  [disabled]="!formModel.valid || formModel.pristine" (click)="onLogin()"
> 
</button>
```

Because of this reason, tuples aren't a good choice for this purpose. Key-value pairs wouldn't have such problem:

```
  "es" : {
    "MSG_USER_1" : "Por favor, introduzca sus datos de acceso",
    "MSG_USER_BUTTONS" : { ACCEDER: Síganos }
  }
```

It is beneficial to provide an abstraction that won't require to access message object directly - a service and a pipe that will return a value for language in use and specified path, like `{{ 'MSG_USER_BUTTONS.LOGIN' | translate }}`, this is how it is usually done. There are several existing i18n solutions that use this approach, e.g. [`ngx-translate`](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core).

Comment: ngx-translate is great choice, instead of re-inventing the wheel by writing one's own i18n logic.

Comment: I've reviewed ngx-translate and it has everything I need for translating the application. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You can write like below:

```
MSGS['MSG_USER_BUTTTTTTTONS'] && MSGS['MSG_USER_BUTTTTTTTONS'][1]
```

If `MSGS['MSG_USER_BUTTTTTTTONS']` is `null` or `undefined` - then, code after `&&` will not execute - so no index error will appear

Comment: This may result in undesirable output if MSGS['MSG_USER_BUTTTTTTTONS'] is falsy (false, 0) but will likely work in this case because of MSG_USER type restrictions.

Comment: This was the solution I thought at first, but I didn't like to duplicate each and all of the translation strings in all the templates.